# facebook sdk and customerchat conflicts fb-root overwrites

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I have two FB plugins on a website, social icons with facebook like. another is customer chat.
Facebook like is initiated first and it creates div with id `fb-root`. And when customer chat tries to init with different id `fb-root-4`

```
fbWidget = document.createElement('div');
      setAttributes(fbWidget, {
        'id': 'fb-root-4',
        'class': 'fb-root'
      });

// adding few events

document.body.appendChild(fbWidget);
```

It does create the widget but doesnt really work. And When I click customer chat, `fb-root` get overwrite with empty value.

What could possibly need to define that it takes `fb-root-4` and create widget on it.

Comment: You only need _one_ `<div id="fb-root"></div>` element in your document, no matter how many FB social plugins you embed. Don’t try and create multiple.

Comment: @CBroe Now, I am using only one fb-root , still doesnt work.

Comment: Show a proper [mre] then, please. (Customer chat plugin only works on the configured domain, so a live example _in addition_ to your code might be helpful.)